# Flutter bloc: updating the state does not re-call BlocBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

I have a page being managed using bloc

here is the `home_state.dart`

```
import 'package:banha/data/models/category.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class HomeState {
  HomeState() : super();
}

class HomeInitial extends HomeState {}

class UpdateCats extends HomeState {
  final List<Category> cats;
  final int rand;
  UpdateCats({@required this.cats,@required this.rand}){
    print(this.cats);
    print(this.rand);
  }
}
```

and the `home_bloc.dart` (**note**: the Random number is just to make sure the state is diff from the prev one)

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:banha/data/models/category.dart';
import 'package:banha/data/network/categories.dart';
import 'package:banha/ui/tabs/home/bloc/home_events.dart';
import 'package:banha/ui/tabs/home/bloc/home_states.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvents, HomeState> {
  getAllCats() {
    dispatch(HomeGetCategories());
  }

  HomeBloc() : super();

  @override
  HomeState get initialState => HomeInitial();

  @override
  Stream<HomeState> mapEventToState(HomeEvents event) async* {
    if (event is HomeGetCategories) {
      yield* _getCats();
    }
  }

  Stream<HomeState> _getCats() async* {
    print("getting cats");
    List<Category> newCats;
    await Network_getAllCategories().then((List<Category> cats) {
      newCats = cats;
    });
    yield UpdateCats(cats: newCats, rand: Random().nextInt(21312545));
  }
}
```

and the page widget:

```
import 'package:banha/ui/category/category.dart';
import 'package:banha/ui/tabs/home/bloc/home_bloc.dart';
import 'package:banha/ui/tabs/home/bloc/home_states.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class ListingsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListingsWidgetState createState() => _ListingsWidgetState();
}

class _ListingsWidgetState extends State<ListingsWidget> {
  final HomeBloc _homeBloc = HomeBloc();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 130,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
      child: BlocListener(
        bloc: _homeBloc,
        listener: (context, state) {
          print(state);
        },
        child: BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
          bloc: _homeBloc,
          builder: (BuildContext context,HomeState state) {
            if(state is UpdateCats){
              print(state.cats);
            }
            return ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1000),
                  onTap: () {
                    HomeBloc().getAllCats();
//                    Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => CategoryPage()));
                  },
....
```

the issue is that in the view(Widget) BlocBuilder is just being called once on initial, but when I try to test changing the state using `HomeBloc().getAllCats();` and then print the new State using this code:

```
if(state is UpdateCats){
              print(state.cats);
            }
```

nothing happens (Builder is not being called ever again), what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Im not sure why, but have you tried *BlocDelegate* to see the state transition, that would be very helpful on debugging If you could provide the logs from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
...
onTap: () {
...
  HomeBloc().getAllCats();
...
},
...
```

It should be `_homeBloc.getAllCats();`

Answer (score 0):

I added `BlocProvider` to the root widget (which is HomePage) and that fixed the issue.

Comment: I just found out you did a strange thing in your code. `HomeBloc().getAllCats();`, you use a local bloc but init a new bloc when dispatching an event. `BlocProvider` is not the real issue since you use local bloc.

Comment: @Tokenyet Exactly